Indices mismatch during merge in pandas
I am trying to merge two dataframes in Python, pandas, df1 and df2.
I am trying to merge them on Column1, and then assign value of Column2 from df2 to df1.
This is my code:
df1 = df1.reset_index()

merged = df1.merge(df2, on='Column1', how='left', indicator=True, suffixes=('_df1', '_df2'))

mask = ( 
     (df1['Column1'].notna()) &
     (merged['_merge'] == 'both')
     )

df1.loc[mask, 'Column2'] = merged.loc[mask, 'Column2_df2']

However, indices get mixed up. And when I print merged, the values are correctly matched. But when I print df1 after assigning values I can see that the values in Column2 are not assign properly, and I can see that the indices do not match indices printed out in merged table.
I have tried adding reset_index when using .loc, not reseting indices at all, but the result is the same.
Here is the example of my dataframes:
(I will include indices that are not related to this example of input, since I am working with big dataframes with milions of records, I cannot think of another way of putting this)
#input 
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Column1': ['A', 'B', None, 'D'],
                    'Column2': [None, None, None, None]
                   })
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Column1': ['B', 'C', 'E', 'A'],
                    'Column2': [10, 20, 30, 40]
                   })

# output of merged:
   Column1_df1  Column1_df2  Column2_df1  Column2_df2  _merge
44           A            A         None           40    both
57           B            B         None           10    both

# output of df1 after .loc:
   Column1  Column2 
0       A        30     
1       B        10  
3    None      None
6       D      None

# expected output of df1 after .loc:
   Column1  Column2 
44       A       30     
57       B       40  
3     None     None
6        D     None

Thank you in advance for your help!

Can you provide a [mre] for clarity with the matching expected output? If it helps you can reuse or modify the one from my answer.

@mozway I have edited the question and included my examples, hope it can help you, to help me :)

Thanks, but please also provide the expected output. The exact issue is unclear, have you tested my map?

@mozway I have provided the expected output. I have tried to map, however I get error because I have duplicate values in df1 in Column1 (however there are other columns that make the entire row not duplicate, so I cannot deduplicate dataframe on Column1)
(this is the error for maping: pandas.errors.InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects)

IIUC, you could avoid using a merge and rather go for a map, which makes it easier to not have to track the indices:
df1['Column2'] = (df1['Column1']
                  .map(df2.set_index('Column1')['Column2'])
                  .fillna(df1['Column2'])
                 )

A fix of your approach would be:
merged = (df1.reset_index()
          .merge(df2, on='Column1', how='left',
                 indicator=True,
                 suffixes=('_df1', '_df2'))
          .set_index('index')
         )

mask = df1['Column1'].notna() & merged['_merge'].eq('both')

df1.loc[mask, 'Column2'] = merged.loc[mask, 'Column2_df2']

Example:
# input
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Column1': ['A', 'B', None, 'D'],
                    'Column2': [1, 2, 3, 4]
                   })
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Column1': ['B', 'C', 'E', 'A'],
                    'Column2': [10, 20, 30, 40]
                   })

# output
  Column1  Column2
0       A     40.0
1       B     10.0
2    None      3.0
3       D      4.0

